# Error uploading file in php

Tags: php

Using Dreamweaver CS6,I have a problem in uploading files.

The ERROR is "INVALID FILE"

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
       && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
       && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
       {
         if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
         {
           echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
         }
         else
         {
           echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
           echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
           echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
           echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
         }
       }
       else
       {
         echo "Invalid file";
       }
?>
```

Comment: What does `echo $_FILES["file"]["type"];` show when this happens?

Comment: There are also many instances your code would go to the "Invalid File" statement. You should split your tests (file type, size, extension) into separate if blocks to know where it failed.

Comment: [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) is nowhere to be found. [**Read the manual**](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file), then add it.

Comment: OP won't have a choice @Populus Uploading code as it is, is almost worthless.

Comment: He needs to get past this little hurdle first, before tackling `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: Probably the form doesn't have an `enctype` or element isn't named, etc. etc. Could be anything. I for one, am not "going there". @Populus

Comment: yes `enctype` is probably the most common first mistake people make :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"]== 0) {

   $upload_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/photos/";

   if (file_exists($upload_dir)) {
      if (is_writable($upload_dir)) {
          $target = $upload_dir; 
          $newName=$_SESSION['theUsername'];
          $target = $target . basename($newName);
          $moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "$target");
      } else {
          echo 'Upload directory is not writable<br>';
      }
   } else {
      echo 'Upload directory does not exist.<br>';
   }
}
```